# Definition of a set: „conceived as a whole“

Tags: set-theory

According to George Cantor „a set is a well defined collection of distinct objects of our perception or of our thought, to be conceived as a whole“.
What does „conceived as a whole“ mean?
Does it just mean that we don’t think of the elements of a set separately, but think of them together?

Comment: A set is a collection of elements and not the elements themselves, just as a bag with one apple inside is not itself an apple.

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
But what is then meant by collection. 
Let’s say we look at a set with one element. Couldn’t one say that this set is just the element?

Comment: No. ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: That's like ordering a bowl of soup at a restaurant, and they serve it to you without a bowl.

Comment: If the word „collection“ it is to be understood colloquially, i.e. as a group of thinks, then a set consisting of one element would be a group of one thing or just the thing itself. 
- I’m not arguing, I just want you to understand my point of view

Comment: I understand that colloquially people blur the distinction between a thing and a "group" of that single thing, but this is the math stack exchange, not the English usage stack exchange, and we don't do that here. Like religiously, we don't. Fanatically. Assiduously. Persistently and faithfully.

Comment: There's nothing that deep about what George Cantor is saying. He's just saying a set is just one collection of elements. I'm pretty sure "conceived as a whole" means to think of the elements put together as if you put fruits (elements) in a basket (set). If that collection has one element, then it has one element and that's it. Whether or not George Cantor had that in mind is beyond us, but we can at least get the just of what he was writing.

Comment: This question is better asked in History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange. The sentence only makes sense in the historical context that Cantor was working in. Modern axiomatic set theory is advanced much more beyond what Cantor started.

Comment: I vaguely recall that at an early point in the development of things-like-set-theory, there was some advocacy to consider $\{x\}=x$, that is, identify singleton sets with their unique elements... But this turned out to create technical troubles.

Answer (score 4):

The idea is that if you think about infinity in a pre-19th century mindset, you most likely think of it as somehow a progression that is unbounded. As though you are computing something, and the larger the input, the larger the output gets.

But set theory is predicated on something else. We can collect *all of these outputs into one object*. We are not computing $f(x)$ for more and more $x$s, instead, we are just assuming that $f$ itself is given, start to, well, "finish".

The simplest example, perhaps, is that of the natural numbers. Instead of saying that $0$ is a natural number, and that if $n$ is a natural number, then $n+1$ is a natural number, and merely stopping there (where we can compute larger and larger natural numbers), set theory asserts that there is a set of **all** natural numbers. We don't need to compute anything, all the numbers are already there.

Comment: You should mention [finitism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitism) as objections to "infinite objects". Because while most people can just accept treating all infinitely many natural numbers as one collection, if you're not careful with how to define things like sets of sets satisfying some property (Cantor's naive set theory) then paradoxes can quickly arise.